# Produce error when document exceeds a page length

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing, error-writing

I tried making an fatal error when the document exceeds a set pagelimit. I think there is some problem with my if statement, because although the document exceeds the limit there is no error. The idea was to get the last page of the document and do a simple if statement: if lastpage > pagelimit then produce error. I also added a package option `longdocument` for

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\newif\if@longdoc
\DeclareOption{longdocument}{\@longdoctrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{No option ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{pagelimit}
\setcounter{pagelimit}{2}

\newcommand*{\thelastpage}{%
  \the\numexpr(\getrefbykeydefault{LastPage}{page}{0})\relax
}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}

\if@longdoc
\else
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \msg_new:nnnn {mypackage}{pagenumber}{Document~has~too~many~pages!}{Reduce~number~of~pages~or~use~another~package}
    
    \int_compare:nNnTF {\thelastpage} > {\thepagelimit}
        { \msg_fatal:nn {mypackage}{pagenumber} }
        {}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\fi

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{mypackage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I also concidered to check if the page limit was exceeded for each page, and then just output the pages below the limit. However, I think this will be somewhat computationally demanding (?).

Is therer also a way to output the pages up to `\thepagelimit` and ignore the rest?

Comment: packages are read in the preamble and so you are testing before the aux file has been read so the page count is not known

Comment: why use  label system that at best will not give an error until the next run? It would be much simpler and better user feedback to simply put a test for value{page} > thepagelimit  in the page head and give an error if exceeded

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How would you go about using feedback in the page head?

Comment: just  use fancyhdr or whatever you normally use and put `\ifnum\value{page}>10 \PackageError{abc}{too many pages}{}\fi` in the page head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the best way to do this but I found a solution using `fancyhdr` and adding some code at the start of every page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\newif\if@longdoc
\DeclareOption{longdocument}{\@longdoctrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{No option ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{pagelimit}
\setcounter{pagelimit}{2}

\newcommand*{\thelastpage}{%
  \the\numexpr(\getrefbykeydefault{LastPage}{page}{0})\relax
}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}

\if@longdoc
\else
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \msg_new:nnnn {mypackage}{pagenumber}{Document~has~too~many~pages!}{Reduce~number~of~pages~or~use~another~package}
    
    \fancypagestyle{limit}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead{
    \ifnum\value{page}>\thepagelimit
        { \msg_fatal:nn {mypackage}{pagenumber} }
        {}
    \fi}}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\fi

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{mypackage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{limit}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]